# Usb flash drive with used sapce but no files in it

Tags: usb, files, flash, disk-usage

I have a 16 GB usb flash drive. It has ~9 GB used space and ~6 GB free space as seen on `Disk Utility`. When I open the directory there are no files in it.

Also `ls -al` gives

```
thanos@thanos-laptop:/media/DCBD-FA98$ ls -al
total 12
drwx------ 2 thanos thanos 8192 Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root   root   4096 Apr 30 13:31 ..
```

Any idea on how to see what are those files in the drive?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the flash drive has been removed unsafely and the filesystem is messed up. Try using fsck to check it and it will likely report lost sectors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The `fsck` didn't show any errors or lost sectors. What I did was to format the drive and everything seem to be OK now!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to use `Photo Rec` under `Test Disk` to retrieve the data.

Then I formatted the usb flash drive and all the 16 GB were there ready to be used.